# Map Frame group not visible on Insert ribbon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, layouts, map-frame

I am trying to add a data frame in ArcGIS Pro 2.8, but the **Map Frame** group is not visible on the **Insert** ribbon. I tried customizing the ribbon but it seems ArcGIS Pro thinks it's already there. The option to add it is also greyed out.

How can make the ribbon group appear or, alternatively, find another way to create a data frame?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data frames are used in ArcMap and the similar object in ArcGIS Pro is a Map Frame.

Map Frames can only be inserted into a Layout view but it looks like you are trying to insert them into a Map view.